# Excel - VBA code to export cell data to word document

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some issues with some VBA code. What I am trying to do is export code from Excel cells and import them into a Word document in a text field.

Here is the code I have.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Acer Windows 7\Desktop\test.docx"
    With objWord.ActiveDocument
      .Text1.Value = ws.Range("A1").Value
      .Text2.Value = ws.Range("B1").Value
      .Text3.Value = ws.Range("C1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This code takes static cells and exports them into a Word document. What I need is a link or button on each row that will export that code from said row and put them into the word document.

Example if I click the link/button on row 4 it takes the data from C4, E4, F4

Is this possible? I am not sure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If there are many rows it can be a bit cumbersome to add a button for each row. I suggest to only use 1 button that exports the selected row. So you only have to maintain 1 button/sub instead of many.

`Cells(Row, Column)` can be used here.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Dim objWord As Object
    Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    objWord.Visible = True
    objWord.Documents.Open "C:\Users\Acer Windows 7\Desktop\test.docx"
    With objWord.ActiveDocument
      .Text1.Value = ws.Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Value
      .Text2.Value = ws.Cells(Selection.Row, 2).Value
      .Text3.Value = ws.Cells(Selection.Row, 3).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

The code above would always use the row of cell which is selected. So first you select the row that you like to export and then you press the button that runs `test()`.

Comment: when i run that code now for some reason i get a box that comes up and says 

"Object doesn't support this property or method"

I havent seent this before

Comment: I forgot to add the `.Value` sorry. I edited my answer.

Comment: Its ok. I appreicate the help. 
I added the .Value at the end of each selection statement. I still seem to get the same error. When i press the button it opens the word document and throws the error. I wonder if its because i am now using word 2016

Comment: Ok I didn't test the code because I assumed that the code that you posted was working (excepting that it can only export line 1). But if it doesn't work then it would be hard to find some help here.

Comment: So i finally have some code that works. The Selection.Row is amazing. I just have one question. is there away that i can select multiple rows with it?